# How do I split a string to get the last word or 2 words in a string but do not know the number of characters or ending words?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

To be more specific than the title... here is one example of a string to use: "You have received 25 dollars from John Doe" I need nameDonated to get just the name John or John Doe depending on if the string has first name or first and last name. Below is the code I have showing John Doe in the string but it only gets John and not the full name John Doe. I am using Visual Basic 2010. Can anyone help?

```
Dim myString As String = "You have received 25 dollars from John Doe"

Dim fields() As String = myString.Split(" ")

Dim numberDollars As String = fields(3).Substring(0)

Dim nameDonated As String = fields(6).Substring(0)

' outputs John donated 25 dollars
TextBox1.Text = nameDonated & " donated " & numberDollars & " dollars."
```

Comment: Do you understand *why* you get "john" instead of  the full name?

Comment: Yes, the fields 6 goes to the sixth space and starts there... then the substring 0 is the ending which is the next word. I need the code to know if there are 2 words or 1 word depending on if the person entered just first name or first and last name. i guess i could do a nameDonated1 and nameDonated2 and dim another statement to put them together... but I was hoping there was a better way than doing that

Comment: There isnt anything in NET to distinguish verbs from nouns from articles from anything else.  Also, your `SubString` isnt doing anything

Comment: thank you plutonix... i tried taking the .substring off and it still works. thank you for explaining that my substring wasnt doing anything.

Comment: ok, i added a fields(7) to get the last name and put the 2 nameDonated together and it works with both names now but when just one name comes along in the sting i get an out of range error. maybe i need to do a trim or something else... not sure... i will keep trying

Comment: Is it always in the form "You have received x dollars from y"?

Comment: yes it is always the same format except y could be a first name only or y could be a first name and a last name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's always in the same format, "You have received x dollars from y", you can split the string based on that format.

```
Dim myString As String = "You have received 25 dollars from John Doe"
' split into {"You have received 25 dollars", "John Doe"}
Dim mySplitString1 As String() = myString.Split(New String() {" from "}, 0)
' and take the second item which has the name
Dim donorName As String = mySplitString1(1)
' then split the first item into {"You", "have", "received", "25", "dollars"}
Dim mySplitString2 As String() = mySplitString1(0).Split(" ")
' and take the fourth item which has the amount
Dim dollarAmount As Single = Single.Parse(mySplitString2(3))

TextBox1.Text = String.Format("{0} donated {1:0} dollars", donorName, dollarAmount)
```

Sometimes the simplest answer is the best. Using your original code, change the name assignment to

```
Dim nameDonated As String = fields(6) & If(fields.Length = 8, " " & fields(7), "")
```

Comment: `Dim nameDonated As String = fields(6) & If(fields.Length = 8, " " & fields(7), "")` works too

Comment: Dim nameDonated As String = fields(6) & If(fields.Length = 8, " " & fields(7), "") works like a dream. thank you so much Verdolino for helping me. :)